# AngularJS: enable a submit button when a valid email address has been entered

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building a simple demo in AngularJS to help me understand how it all works. My next task I would like to achieve is to **only enable the submit button when a valid email address has been entered**. I would like to know where to start with this, and what I need to understand to achieve such functionally. Examples would be perfect.

This is what I have so far:

I have a  `ui-view`:

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

Within this view I load my main template:

**app.config:**

```
   $stateProvider
        .state('route1', {

            url: "/ID/:slug",
            templateUrl: "/static/sign_up.html",
            controller: "myData"
        })
```

The myData just load some ajax stuff I use.

**Template sign_up.html**:

```
<h1>{{ data.name }}</h1>
<form action="">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label" for="id_email">Email
                    *</label>

                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                        <input class="form-control" id="id_email" name="email"
                        type="text">
                    </div>
                </div><button class="btn btn-lg" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: It's all explained in the documentation: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this link for documentation regarding validating email in AngularJS. It has good examples there as well.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:input.email

The way it  works is, you name your form 'MyForm' (for example) and once an input field with `type="email"` in this form has a valid email, `myForm.$error.email` becomes `false`, so you can set up your submit button, using `ng-disabled` like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-lg" type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$error.email">Submit</button>
```

So, by default `ng-disabled = true`, and it becomes enabled only when there's a valid email

Do check out the documentation and examples,

Hope it helps,

Ulugbek

Answer (score 1):

Name the form and then use the following... (Also, check the documentation as in comment)

```
<button class="btn btn-lg" type="submit" ng-disabled="yourform.$invalid">Submit</button>
```